# Any way of simplifying this Scala code (pattern matching)?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have some values provided by the user as `Option[String]`. I want to validate them only if they are non-empty.

The validation just checks that the string can be converted to an int, and is not less that 0.

Is there any way of simplifying this code, or making it more readable?

```
val top: Option[String] = ...
val skip: Option[String] = ...

val validationErrors = new ListBuffer[Err]()

top match {
  case Some(x) => if (x.toIntOpt.isEmpty || x.toIntOpt.get < 0) validationErrors += PositiveIntegerRequired("$top")
}
skip match {
  case Some(x) => if (x.toIntOpt.isEmpty || x.toIntOpt.get < 0) validationErrors += PositiveIntegerRequired("$skip")
}
```

And here is the toIntOpt helper:

```
def toIntOpt: Option[Int] = Try(s.toInt).toOption
```

Comment: `object PositiveInt { def unapply(repr: String): Option[Int] = Try(repr.toInt).filter(_ >= 0)` and `top match { case Some(PositiveInt(x)) => ???; case _ => sys.error(s"Invalid int: $repr") }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be simplified a lot, by making use of `flatMap` and `for-comprehensions` and `collect`:

```
def checkInt[A](stringOpt: Option[String], a: A): Option[A] = for {
  s <- stringOpt
  i <- s.toIntOpt if (i < 0)
} yield a

val validationErrors = List(
  checkInt(top, PositiveIntegerRequired("$top")),
  checkInt(skip, PositiveIntegerRequired("$skip"))
).collect {
  case Some(x) => x
}
```

The first function `checkInt`returns a value `a` if the original `Option` was non-empty and contained an invalid negative integer.

Then we put both into a List and collect only the values that are non-empty, resulting in a `List` of `Err` with no need for creating an intermediate `Buffer`.

An even easier way to do something like this can be found with the `Validated` type found in the cats library: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html

Comment: The guard is not part of a generator (i.e. the `i <-` is wrong). You might make the `a` parameter call-by-name so that it doesn't get evaluated unnecessarily. You don't need the `collect`, just `flatten` the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `for-comprehension`s is to use a `map` with a `filter`.

```
top.map(toIntOpt)
   .filter(i => i.getOrElse(-1) < 0)
   .foreach(_ => validationErrors += PositiveIntegerRequired("$top"))
```

The `map` call will result in a `Option[Option[Int]]` which is then filtered based on the value of the nested `Option` (defaulting to `-1` if the option is `None`).